# Javascript fade two box in same div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

i can't change the div output , i have this js but this load only for second div :
[code]

```
   var next = null;
    var outer = jQuery('#wp_bannerize-2 > #banners');
    var current = outer.find('.box:first');
    current.fadeIn();
    function fade() {
        if (current.next('div.box').length > 0) {
            next = current.next('div.box');
        } else {
            next = outer.find('.box:first');
        }

        current.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn();
        current = next;
        setTimeout(fade, 1000); //5secondi
    }
    // start the process
    fade();


  var next = null;
    var outer = jQuery('#wp_bannerize-3 > #banners');
    var current = outer.find('.box:first');
    current.fadeIn();
    function fade() {
        if (current.next('div.box').length > 0) {
            next = current.next('div.box');
        } else {
            next = outer.find('.box:first');
        }

        current.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn();
        current = next;
        setTimeout(fade, 1000); //5secondi
    }
    // start the process
    fade();
```

[/code]
How can i solve it ? i think i will replace the js var next and var next2.
LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/EmQmL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what purpose you are doing like this. You have so many duplicate variable declaration in your code. For that reason it is not working. Update your code like below, it will work. But I cant tell this is the perfect answer. For time being you can use this.

```
      var next1 = null;
    var outer1 = jQuery('#wp_bannerize-2 > #banners');
    var current1 = outer1.find('.box:first');
    current1.fadeIn();
    function fade1() {
        if (current1.next('div.box').length > 0) {
            next1 = current1.next('div.box');
        } else {
            next1 = outer1.find('.box:first');
        }

        current1.fadeOut();
        next1.fadeIn();
        current1 = next1;
        setTimeout(fade1, 1000); //5secondi
    }
    // start the process
    fade1();


  var next = null;
    var outer = jQuery('#wp_bannerize-3 > #banners');
    var current = outer.find('.box:first');
    current.fadeIn();
    function fade() {
        if (current.next('div.box').length > 0) {
            next = current.next('div.box');
        } else {
            next = outer.find('.box:first');
        }

        current.fadeOut();
        next.fadeIn();
        current = next;
        setTimeout(fade, 1000); //5secondi
    }
    // start the process
    fade();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EmQmL/4/)